# How to silence a noisy typer

Tags: noise

I work in an office that's by and large very quiet and relaxed... until recently. A new member moved onto our team and oh sweet jesus does he make a noise... typing.

He literally smashes the return key and spacebar so much so that my desk actually shakes and my monitor shakes. I'm a programmer and find it super distracting. Normally I try listening to music but that's not always possible especially if i'm pair programming with another developer.

If it was someone whistling and humming I would politely ask them to stop. But to ask someone to type quieter... seems... it just seems a bit cheeky even if he does sound like he's using a hammer to type.

How do I deal with this issue its driving me insane and its starting to affect my work as i'm finding it increasingly difficult to concentrate.

I know some people do type louder than others, especially on mechanical keyboards but this is unreal, i've never seen anyone slam his hands on his keyboard like this fella.

Comment: Maybe it is the keyboard and not him?

Comment: No. As I mentioned my monitor shakes. We all use the same keyboards. Even if he had the clickiest keys in the universe they wouldn't amplify the force of his typing to the degree in which my monitor is shaking all over the place.

Comment: How are other people in your team coping with it? Or are you the only one affected?

Comment: Havnt really talked to my team about it. I see people looking over their desks sometimes when he's smashing the return key.
I dont really want to start an angry mob or anything. I'm also not sure how close some of them are to him friendship wise. I dont want to offend the guy as he's a nice guy. He's just irritating me.
I guess it doesnt really matter if he's bothering other people though. He's bothering me, I cant turn it off or ignore it i've tried. What i'm looking for now is some advice on what to do about it. Inaction isnt an option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loud keyboards and coworkers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9694/loud-keyboards-and-coworkers)

Comment: @gnat I don't see that as a dup and it is closed.

Comment: I don't get how someone has strong enough fingers to shake a desk and monitor.

Comment: Dude....I work in a small office with a couple old school programmers who use the old IBM keyboards because of the special keys they use for their mainframe systems.  I work a little bit with some of it too, but ditched the console and keyboard for emulation software on the PC.  I couldn't deal with the incessant clicking.  However, even though they also use the emulation software they insist on those damned keyboards.

Comment: @Gnat It's from the other perspective, the OP isn't the noisy typer as per your suggested dupe

Comment: There are two types of typers, those that type and those that want to be heard typing.

Comment: Is it possible that the enter key and/or the space bar on that keyboard is a bit dodgy, and he's gotten into the habit of hitting them harder so as to avoid - from his perspective - the frustration of interrupted typing flow? Perhaps that could be a good way to start the conversation; "oh is your spacebar giving you gyp as well? Yeah mine was like that before, here, let me show you how to request a new one..."

Comment: @paparazzo it's all in the wrist

Comment: Is he older?  Specifically, someone who learned on a manual typewriter?

Answer (score 15):

He has no idea what a nuisance he has become to you, so any idea that involves bringing in HR or his manager is overkill at this stage.

There is going to be nothing more effective than having a quick, non-confrontational chat with him to the tune of "*Dude, you're driving me bonkers the way you pound your keyboard...Can we find a solution that works for the both of us?*"

Before you do this though, research some solutions you can propose, e.g. different keyboard, soft mousepads under the keyboard, etc.

Comment: Before you do this - be sure to think how you would react if someone said *your* normal typing style was disruptive to *them*. Approach with care.

Comment: I would focus on the fact this person types so hard it makes a desk shake. Seems excessive not too much to ask to stop.

Comment: My point is, the heavy typist is almost certainly just typing in the way they have always typed. They may, for example, have at some time used a mechanical typewriter which needed more force on the keys. Asking them to change now, even if they could, could very well impinge on *their* productivity / job satisfaction / willingness to work alongside the OP.

Comment: @JoeStevens: A lack of willingness to find a mutually agreeable compromise is a considerable problem as to how that employee expects to be treated by their employer. Avoiding addressing an actual problem on the off chance that the person causing the issue will get offended; implicitly allows them to refuse to compromise; while also showing bad employee management in general. Even if what you said is true, then the OP has an _equal_ right to be offended that he's seated next to such a loud typer, which renders us in a stalemate as to which employee gets what they want.

Comment: Yes Its quite obvious I suppose I should just have a chat to him, but im a coward and hate confrontation. Its difficult because its literally his job to type. As I said before if it was humming or whilsting id have no problem with saying "could you stop that please"

But its like hey stop typing you're too loud...just seems cheeky.

The keyboard is a basic microsoft keyboard, so its not even mechanical. I dont think putting anything underneath it will help.

What ive noticed is when he's typing letters its not too bad its when he presses space or enter he literally smashes them.

Comment: Perhaps focusing on the irritant ("it bothers me when my monitor shakes, could we put cushioning between our desks") would be better than on the person ("YOU bother me when typing").

Comment: Someone once mentioned to me that occasionally my typing would get a little loud. I had no idea, and I simply didn't do that anymore from then on.

Answer (score 2):

Just say "whoa" and laugh a few times he does it, he'll get the hint. 
It doesn't need to turn nasty and you dont need to embarrass him by "having a chat" about it.

Comment: I know someone who did that with a co-worker who answered the phone very loudly, and it didn't work.

Comment: It was probably worth the try tho...

Answer (score 1):

Tell him that what he does is damaging his body. Seriously.

There is very, very little force needed to type on any normal keyboard. All the noise that you hear is force going into the table and making it shake, and an equal amount of force is going into his fingers, hands, and arms, and does damage. That's why a good typist has their fingers at the shortest possible distance to the keyboard. Usually the fingers are actually resting on the keyboard.